# If the Earth is in constant motion then why do we say that an object is in a state of rest?

Tags: reference-frames, terminology, rotational-kinematics, relative-motion, equilibrium

I got this question as my physics class homework for tomorrow. Anyone please help me out.

> If Earth constantly rotates and revolves, then how can we call an object in a state of rest?

Comment: "*relative to*" is the phrase you need to know here.

Comment: I just read in 8th standard and don't know much about it...

Comment: What does "read in 8th standard" mean?

Comment: @Joe: "Learnt in year 8 / 8th grade", I would guess. Seems pretty obvious?

Comment: @Joe I think 8th Standard is the first year of secondary school in the Indian system. The OP is from Kashmir.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"A state of rest" is a relative term. Relative means - measured in comparison to the things around it.

When you sit in a train and sip from a cup of coffee, you can do so because the cup is still *relative to you* even though both of you might be hurtling through the countryside at 200 km/h.

For most experiments, objects can be considered "at rest" if they don't move relative to the things around them. But the "frame of reference" (the thing that you consider "stationary") does matter.

For example - if you sit in a car that accelerates, you might be "at rest" relative to the car, but you can feel yourself being pushed into the seat of the car by an invisible force. Similarly, there are measurable effects on earth that are due to the fact that Earth rotates about its axis (for example - the way air rotates around a low pressure region is a consequence of the rotation of the Earth), and even effects that relate to the motion around the sun (including the tides).

Physicists call accelerating and rotating frames of reference "non-inertial", and say that observations in such frames "give rise to fictitious forces" - that is, if you *think* your non-inertial frame is stationary, you will also *think* that a force has appeared out of thin air. Such as the force that pushes you into the seat of the accelerating car. Or the "force" that makes you spill your drink when the car goes over a bump (and your "frame of reference" suddenly accelerates).

But for many "in classroom" experiments, we can ignore all these things. Much of physics (and science) is about knowing what you can ignore, and when you can ignore it.

Comment: It's worth noting that part of Relativity is the principle that the laws of physics are consistent for two objects in the same (inertial) frame of reference regardless of the speed with which that frame is moving.

Comment: Oh, also, `"give rise to fictitious forces"` ... best known example of this is centrifugal force :)

Comment: Beside being an excellent answer, the last paragraph should get you double upvotes privilege (if there was such a thing)

Comment: @WoJ - thanks. I prefer to exert my influence on this site through my answers and comments, rather than by clicking an anonymous up/down arrow.

Comment: @Floris I was actually thinking of upvotes to your answer counting double  :)  I find your last paragraph particularly wise, it is a shame this is not advertised more when teaching tangible subjects (that is science).

Comment: @WoJ - that is nice of you. You are right, it is a shame when this is not instilled from an early age. Often, the desire to be "accurate" leads to a false hunt to account for "every effect, no matter how small". This is the same mentality that makes people write the result of their calculation as `1.23456` instead of `1.2` in cases where the error in their answer is on the order of 10% ("But, there are more digits on my calculator! Right there! I should copy them down just in case!").

Comment: @Floris: I was about to add to my comment a story I had when teaching Physics to engineering students. I had an exercise about the speed of a skydiver when landing. One of the students wrote 578.57 km/h. I told him to think for a moment on his answer and try to imagine the landing at that speed (my next exercise would be to estimate the depth of the hole he would make). His answer was to add more digits... That's why I am scared of bridges :)

Comment: @WoJ - one streamlined skydiver! As for the bridge - after calculating the maximum stress as 3.14159265 x 10^8 N/m^2, the engineer will add a factor 5x for safety... so your bridge will be OK. Did you see my user profile?

Comment: I'd just say, one must be patient while teaching...  thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 6):

Revolving around the sun is equivalent to free fall around the sun, so the revolution allows you not to 'feel' the sun's gravity.

The rotation of the earth is something that can be measured: (i) a centrifugal force which is a small offset on gravity, and (ii) causes the coriolis force. Both these are small effects, so can often be ignored for laboratory experiments.

Comment: Now I can upvote it!

Answer (score 3):

"Rest, in physics, refers to an object being stationary *relative to a particular frame of reference* or another object." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_(physics)) (emphasis mine)

**While on Earth, the planet is often treated as the default frame of reference.**  It is not a perfect frame of reference, but for many purposes it is good enough.  Since [there is no absolute frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_(physics)#cite_ref-2), some frame of reference must be chosen, and for us earth-dewllers the frame defined by the earth itself is familiar and often easy to work with.  Being a [non-inertial frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inertial_reference_frame) there are some [fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force#Fictitious_forces_on_Earth) that may need to be accounted for, but for many purposes those forces are negligible and when they're not we have well established methods to account for them.

Whenever a frame of reference is not specified, it is usually expected that you will assume a frame of reference that matches the assumptions used in similar exercises or in discussions preceding the exercises.  The two sets of assumptions I have seen most often are

1. "As-on-earth", assuming fictitious forces are negligible, ignoring surface curvature & air resistance, and assuming a constant gravitational field, and
2. An abstract inertial frame with no gravity or atmosphere.

Both are often confined to 2 dimensions.  If you're not sure, you can usually ask for clarification, or give multiple answers for different frames.

Comment: Very nice answer. Not sure I agree with the very last paragraph. A frame of reference is usually 3D even if your solution might be in a 2D plane. And the "ask for clarification" part is a test strategy, not physics. But upvoting for everything before that.

Answer (score 1):

Solving lots of physics problems involved you choosing a frame of reference. As long as all your formulations are from a particular frame of reference, for example the energy of objects then the laws will work.
Since you are also travelling with the object, (as the earth rotates) it is easier to say you are at rest. If you are travelling at constant velocity relative to something at rest, the physics will work if you consider you are at rest and the other thing is travelling at constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in a moving vehicle and see trees or buildings, who is moving? Are you moving forward, or are the trees and buildings moving backward? Its counter-intuitive for beginners but both these views are absolutely correct.

We can only describe the motion of an object from a reference frame. A reference frame is a specific configuration from where you can observe/describe the system. The earth indeed is moving, but the objects on it are moving along with it too, and hence *with respect* to the Earth, the objects are at rest. (i.e. they move with the same velocity as the Earth.) (e.g. an object which is stationary with respect to you is not stationary when observed by someone moving by!)

An object's relative velocity w.r.t you determines whether it is at rest with respect to you or not. If there are two objects $A$ and $B$ (with velocities $V_A,V_B$), the relative velocity of $A$ with respect to $B$ is $$V_B-V_A$$

This is zero if $A$ and $B$ are at rest with respect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything in the universe is moving relative to some thing else, we can only say that an object is at rest by making **the object itself** the frame of reference!